# take back the Firebase notification on the server side

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my web app I notify a group of users using FCM. When the first user reacts to the notification, the others loose the chance to respond (Say it is a game).

I want to take back the sent notification to other users and It is obvious that I can not implement the logic inside the android app (Because only the server knows who won the game).

Is there a way to take back the notification sent using Google Firebase on the server side?

Comment: Take Back when? The notification has already reached user? Or when still in Firebase (not yet in users devices)?

Comment: After a successful delivery. @Xenolion

Comment: There is no direct way for that! What you should do is to send another notification ( data message) and when users get that Remove any other notification in their Android devices!

Comment: I believe your game is not well served with FCM. Your prisms that all notifications will be sent simultaneously? Then you cannot rely on FCM messaging system for your delivery system. Individual delivery of some Messages may experience some random delay. Not much fun playing a game where you are randomly disadvantaged.

Comment: @Xenolion Good Idea but I don't want to cancel all notifications. I have to just remove the outdated one. Is that long notificaton ID in FCM response is the ID of notificatoin used  in  notificationManager.cancel(id)?

Comment: No message id of Firebase has no relation with that in Android. Do this, when sending your data message add a unique id as the part of data then use for `notify` method. Now you can cancel a notification if the because you know the id used!